# Redirect all incoming traffic on a domain to non-www HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I thought I could get this accomplished using the following, but it's looping...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What do I need to do to make sure all instances of the domain go to https://example.com without looping?

Answer (score 3):

Your first line checks if the host is what you are redirecting to. You don't need to check `HTTPS_HOST`, because in https, the host is still the same (it's from the request header, `Host:`).

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: And that also pushes the non-https, non-www to the https?

Comment: @DavidBorough no it doesn't, I've edited the answer to account for non-https.

Comment: Works great when I put it at the top of my .htaccess file, thanks!